# Refresh RDLC DataSet in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdlc

I'm modifying an SSRS report inside a Visual Studio project.  The report is based on a view in SQL Server that I've modified.  The DataSet properties refuses to pick up the new columns in the view without manually editing the XML .rsd file.  Searching through these posts and on other sites going back as much as 10 years, there seems to be a "Refresh Fields" solution on the DataSet properties but my DataSet Properties dialog has no such button.  I don't want to delete the data set and lose all the report formatting that is already done.  There has to be a way to update the data set with new fields.

Comment: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/add-edit-refresh-fields-in-the-report-data-pane-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#to-refresh-the-field-collection-in-the-report-data-pane-for-a-shared-dataset)

Comment: _"To refresh the field collection in the Report Data Pane for a shared dataset

    In the Report Data pane, right-click the dataset, and then click Query.

    Click Refresh Fields.

    On the report server, the shared dataset query runs and returns the current field collection."_

Comment: There is no "query" option in the dataset.

Comment: When I right-click the dataset, the options I have from the context menu are Refresh, Delete and DataSet Properties.  Refresh does nothing.  The DataSet properties dialog has buttons for Help, OK, Cancel.